# How to call var from another form in C#

Tags: c#, forms, global-variables

i have two form in C#... i declare 3 var in form 1 pic, pic2 and picC.

In zoomform i instantiate the form1 object to try to get the variables values.. but i ran into stackoverflow exception...

```
 namespace Disimage
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    zoomForm zf = new zoomForm();

     public Bitmap pic;
            public Bitmap pic2;
            public Bitmap picC;
    }
    }


    namespace Disimage
    {
        public partial class zoomform : Form
        {
            public zoomform()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    Form1 f1 = new Form();

    }
    }
```

Comment: no vote or correct answer for this? So many answers are posted, might be somebody from them solve your problem or at least helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because when you call

zoomForm zf = new zoomForm();  it will create a Form1 object which again create ZoomForm object results in a cycle and eventually  results in the stackoverflow

it is^similar to the fllowing suisidal code

```
Class A
{
        A a ;

   A()
   {
        a = new A();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's beacause you create an instance of Form1 which contains an instance of zoomForm which contains an instance of Form1 which contains an instance of zoomForm which contains an instance of Form1 which contains an instance of zoomForm which contains an instance of Form1 which contains an instance of zoomForm which contains an instance of Form1 which contains an instance of zoomForm and there goes your stack.

Answer (score 0):

In zoomForm you instanciate a Form1 and in Form1 you instanciate a zoomForm, so your callstack looks like this(assuming you create a zoomForm first):

...
Form1
zoomForm
Form1
zoomForm
Form1
zoomForm
Form1
zoomForm
Form1
zoomForm
Form1
zoomForm
Form1
zoomForm
Form1
zoomForm
...

for about 8 thousand lines or some other way too high number. One easy way to solve this is to not instanciate the objects in the classes but set the objects from the outside.

```
zoomForm zf = new zoomForm();
form f1 = new Form1();
zf.form1 = f1;
f1.zoomForm = zf;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to something like

```
namespace Disimage
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        zoomForm zf;       
        public Bitmap pic;
        public Bitmap pic2;
        public Bitmap picC;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            zf = new zoomForm();
            zf.Parent = this;
        }       
    }
}


namespace Disimage
{
    public partial class zoomform : Form
    {
        Form1 Parent;
        public zoomform()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }   
    }
}
```

If you wish to have a reference to the Parent/Calling form, you need to explicitly set such a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Here i am passing the 3 var to another form by declaring the same value types in another form as public property

```
    namespace Disimage {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    { 
        public Form1()
    { 
            InitializeComponent();

    } 
        private Bitmap pic;
        private Bitmap pic2;
        private Bitmap picC; 
        zoomForm zf = new zoomForm();
        zf.pic = pic;
        zf.pic2 = pic2;
        zf.picC = picC;
        zf.ShowDialog();

    }
}
namespace Disimage
{
    public partial class zoomform : Form 
    {
        public Bitmap pic;
        public Bitmap pic2;
        public Bitmap picC; 
        public zoomform() 
        { 
            InitializeComponent(); 
        } 
        Form1 f1 = new Form(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: No, you're not declaring any properties at all - you've got public *fields*, which is generally a bad idea.